# Trigonometry: $5\sin x\cos y+4\cos x\sin y=0$; $\cot x=2$; need to find $\cot y$

Tags: trigonometry

> Given that $5\sin x\cos y+4\cos x\sin y=0$, and that $\cot x=2$, find the value of $\cot y$.

I don't understand why I got this question wrong. For this question, I drew a right-angled triangle. I then labelled angle $x$ and derived that 2 would be adjacent to $x$ and 1 would be opposite to $x$ because $\cot x=2=\frac21$. With both sides, I was able to work out the hypotenuse as $\sqrt5$.

I labelled angle $y$ as another angle in the right-angled triangle and then got $\cot y=\frac12$.

Comment: Trignomotortery?

Comment: Yes. It is a new word!

Comment: I see it as a portmanteau word made up of the prefix *tri*, a *gnome*, and a portmanteau in the portmanteau: tortery=tortuous+tottery.

Comment: The last part might also be related to "torture/tortury", i.e. the way OP feels about these exercises.

Comment: @TMM You figured it out, well done!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's what you did wrong:

You drew a right angled triangle with an angle $x$. Then you just went and guessed that the other angle was the $y$ you needed to find. Your guess was wrong.

Comment: Why was my guess wrong though?

Comment: Give me a better explanation as to why my guess was incorrect and I'll click your answer as the 'most useful' that's what you all strive for right? To have the most useful answers?

Comment: What do you mean "why was my guess wrong"? It's just wrong. The other angle is not $y$. You can't just draw a random picture and expect everything in that picture to have something to do with your question.

Comment: Maybe you're confused because in other trigonometry problems there is a triangle and one angle is called $x$ and the other $y$. This problem is not the other problems, there's no triangle in this problem. The triangle only exists in your imagination.

Comment: @McFry, I don't think the OP so much "guessed" that $y$ was the other angle as *assumed* that both variables, thought of as angles, must pertain to the same triangle.  (I was composing this and didn't see your reply above until I posted.)

Comment: There was a similar question, I did a while ago. The question was: "Given that tan A = -5/12 and that angle A is obtuse, find the exact value of Sec A." The model solution took my approach and just used the fact that since A was an obtuse angle, it was in the 2nd quadrant which dictated whether it was positive or negative

Comment: @BarryCipra So what you're saying is that not all variables necessarily belong to the same triangle

Comment: @user375494, exactly.

Comment: Yes, and using a triangle to visualize that problem was just fine. You need to keep in mind that the triangle is just a visualization of that problem, and that not every problem can be visualized using the same drawing, or even at all.

Comment: @BarryCipra So then how can I tell when they do and do not?? Or would it have to be given to me explicitly?

Comment: @McFry then when is it fine to use a drawing to visualise a problem? :/

Comment: @user375494 When the drawing actually matches the problem. This problem didn't say that $x$ and $y$ were angles of a right-angled triangle, so you shouldn't draw a right-angled triangle with $x$ and $y$ until you know that such a triangle exists. For this problem, it does not exist, so your drawing made a false assumption that you then used to get a false answer.

Comment: @McFry Oh, I see now. Thanks, for putting up with my stupidity. ;)

Answer (score 1):

by dividing both to  $\sin { x } \cos { y } $ and consider the fact that $\cot { x } =2$ we get $$5\sin { x\cos { y } +4\cos { x } \sin { y } =0, } \\ 5+4\frac { \cos { x } \sin { y }  }{ \sin { x } \cos { y }  } =0\\ 5+4\cot { x } \tan { y } =0\\ 5+\frac { 8 }{ \cot { y }  } =0\\ \cot { y } =-\frac { 8 }{ 5 } $$

Comment: @McFry,i fixed thank you

Comment: I know how to do it, but I'd like to know why the method I originally took is incorrect? If possible...